# Write to Roomle parameter from external page

Tags: roomle

I'm looking to change an internal Roomle parameter from externally from a webpage. I have 3 icon menus within roomle, the webpage that the Roomle is hosted on has users logins, so depending on who has logged in I want to hide certain Roomle Icons Menus, for example if Person1 is logged in I want to set the internal Roomle parameter of allowSplinta==true, allowCB==true, allowTB==true but if Person2 is logged in I want to set allowSplinta==false, allowCB==true, allowTB==false, so Person2 will only see 1 icon menu.

I see from the documentation this seems to be possible but unsure how to implement it, there is a section on the roomle site "Parameter Implementation outside of the configurator iFrame"

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned there is a section in the [docs](https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/#parameter-implementation-outside-of-the-configurator-iframe) which explains this.

Basically you have to make sure the configuration is loaded (await `loadObject`) and then get all the parameters using your configurator instance:

```
const params = await configurator.extended.getParametersOfRootComponent();
```

If you know which parameter you want you can search it in the `params` array:

```
const viewParam = params.find(({key}) => key === 'door');
```

All valid values for this parameter are then stored in `validValues` (`viewParam.validValues`).

You can then use `setParameterOfRootComponent` to set the desired value:

```
configurator.extended.setParameterOfRootComponent(viewParam, value)
```

I created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/parameter-implementation-outside-of-the-configurator-iframe-22js3?file=/index.js) where you can take a look at the full example.

Comment: Thanks for this, looks great, have swapped in a few bits of code to test. So for example I have a parameter in the ROOT part called COMPANY, it has a list of ValidObjects, if I wanted to set the COMPANY to a different validObject what would the syntax be...

Comment: configurator.extended.setParameterOfRootComponent(company, 'Rack Systems')

Comment: All Sorted (I think)!! many thanks for your help!